# SubSonic - Using Sprocs vs in-line code-behind query?

Tags: sql, subsonic, code-behind, stored-procedures

I'm curious about at what extent I should be writing sproc's.  Obviously for actions that require transactions, etc.  However for a simple validation against one table and values within, is it still recommended to use a sproc rather than doing the SubSonic query in the code-behind?

In one respect it does make sense to write the sproc, as the business rules may change for whatever we're trying to validate, and the sproc simply returns a pass/fail value.

Based on that, in an enterprise app - why even bother writing any code-behind queries vs sprocs?

I guess I just answered my own question, but on another note, I'm curious about the actual overhead of one vs the other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had a lot of discussions about this very topic

Here is some reading material

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stored%20procedures%20queries&tab=relevance